# Android widget: PendingIntent on ListView not called with setPendingIntentTemplate and setOnClickFillInIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-widget, android-pendingintent

Have been attempting different approaches to implement an onClick event for the ListView in my widget but with no avail.

My widget is defined in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Widget -->
    <receiver android:name=".widget.AppWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/app_widget_info"/>
    </receiver>

    <service android:exported="false" android:name=".widget.AppWidgetService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
```

My first approach was to use onReceive for receiving the intent and start a different activity:

```
// setPendingIntentTemplate in AppWidgetProvider
    final Intent onClickIntent = new Intent(context, AppWidgetProvider.class);
    onClickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetProvider.CLICK_ACTION);
    onClickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    onClickIntent.setData(Uri.parse(onClickIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    final PendingIntent onClickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            onClickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_schedule_list, onClickPendingIntent);

// and setOnClickFillInIntent in the getViewAt() in RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory class
    final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();

    extras.putInt(TVTracWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.episode_schedule_widget_row, fillInIntent);
```

My second approach was to start the activity directly:

```
// setPendingIntentTemplate in AppWidgetProvider
    TaskStackBuilder builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(context, MainActivity_.class));
    builder.addNextIntent(new Intent(context, EpisodeActivity_.class));
    rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_schedule_list, builder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

// and setOnClickFillInIntent in RemoteViewsFactory getViewAt()
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(EpisodeActivity.showIdExtra, episode.getShow().getId());
    extras.putInt(EpisodeActivity.seasonNrExtra, episode.getSeasonNr());
    extras.putInt(EpisodeActivity.episodeNrExtra, episode.getEpisodeNr());

    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();

    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);

    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.episode_schedule_widget_row, fillInIntent);
```

However, neither approach seems to work.
The pendingIntentTemplate is on the ListView's id and onClickFillInIntent on the parent layout of each row item. Could anyone explain me what could cause the click not to be fired? Thanks in advance!

Sources: [weatherlistwidget](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0///resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/src/com/example/android/weatherlistwidget/index.html) and [App Widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the TextViews inside the item which had textIsSelectable="true".

Comment: Depending on how your list item is laid out, you might also need playing with the `android:clickable` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

For the newer generation of AppWidget builders.

The axiom derived from the newly updated widgets API code is:

If the underlying the `setPendingIntentTemplate()` pending intent is declared with the new mandatory flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` then any changes expected from the `setOnClickFillInIntent()` superposition are ignored.

I.e. change it to MUTABLE.